# Spring can't resolve command line arguments

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm migrating a pretty legacy application to Spring Boot. It is configured with xml and I've got the following snippet there:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="localOverride" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:conf/${ENV}/some.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm starting the app with the following command line:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dserver.port=22222 -DENV=int
```

But it fails on startup with the following message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'ENV' in value "classpath:conf/${ENV}/some.properties"
```

It worked before and now I've got `spring-boot-starter-web`.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:** It doesn't work in `@PropertySource`, not in xml, sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: What spring boot version are you using?
Can you confirm that the config file can be found in target/classes and JAR package.

Comment: @Bluurr Hi, Spring Boot version is 1.4.7, no, there were not this configs but the problem was in resolving environment varibles, not the jars)

Answer (score 2):

When running the application using maven spring boot plugin(like you are doing) you need to specify like this

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--server.port=22222, --ENV=int"
```

If you want to run your application using `java -jar` command. This is the way

```
java -jar -Dserver.port=22222 -DENV=int XYZ.jar
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but now it says "Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: --ENV=int"

Comment: sorry, I've just found a real problem: it doesn't work in PropertySource annotation. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: how r u using this in `@PropertySource`

Comment: this way: @PropertySource( { "classpath:conf/${ENV}/some.properties" })

Comment: where is this conf folder?

Comment: simply /resources/conf dir

Comment: try `@PropertySource( { "classpath:/conf/${ENV}/some.properties" }) `

Answer (score 0):

You should use `#systemEnvironment['propertyName']` or

`#{systemProperties['propertyName']}`

```
 <value>classpath:conf/#{systemEnvironment['ENV']/some.properties</value>
```

Because

```
${propertyName}
```

You can only access properties defined in `.properties` file

Comment: thanks a lot, but I've just figured out it doesn't work in PropertySource annotation. However, it worked with ${} before.